# How to update AssemblyVersion using Update Assembly Info plugin in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to update the version number of my .exe file using Update Assembly Info plugin.
I am using the following configuration:
[image]

But, I keep getting an error
`'$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.r)' is not a valid parameter for attribute 'AssemblyVersion'`

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)` and `$(Rev:.r)` can’t be used as the build-in variable, it can be used in Build number format (Options tab).

The workaround is that:

1. Include $(Rev:.r) in Build number format, such as `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)`
2. Add PowerShell task to add a new variable (Arguments: `-bn $(Build.BuildNumber`)

Script:

```
param(
[string]$bn
)
$d=Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$r=$bn.split("{.}")[-1]
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentVersion]$d$r"
```

3. Then use `currentVersion` variable in subsequent tasks, such as Update Assembly task.